# Removing spaces from text filed value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove spaces in value of a text filed using JS but its not working
Here is what i have tried

**HTML**

```
<input name="lmt_c13" id="lmt_c13" onblur="verifyControlValue(this);" type="number" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
function verifyControlValue(control) {
    control.value = control.value.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    // other functionality based on control value
}
```

but this removes the whole value
I am calling this function on `onblur()` event

Here is the JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4gLb5k4L/8/

Comment: can you add a fiddle?

Comment: `.replace(/\s+/g, '');` will remove spaces so if that isn't working, then something else is wrong with your code that you aren't showing us.

Comment: I updated your Fiddle to add the code in the correct place. This isn't a text field though, it's a number field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a `number` field. `value` will only represent a correct value when a number is entered. Otherwise it will return an empty string.

So really you are running this code:

```
"".replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

Which is why you're getting a blank string back. Either use a `text` field or else let the `number` field do the validation for you.

Comment: actually the thing is that I am loading this page in Android webView and on a specific device Nexus 10 with android 4.4.2 this validation is not working

Comment: @AdilWaqar Then you should use `parseInt`/`parseFloat` instead and do your own validation.

Answer (score 1):

See updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/4gLb5k4L/6/

Why are you using `type="number"` for text? That's your problem.

**HTML**

```
<input name="lmt_c13" id="lmt_c13" type="text"></input>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var input = document.getElementById('lmt_c13');
input.addEventListener('blur', function () {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\s+/g, '');
}, false);
```